# Using sortedArrayUsingSelector: with non-letter characters at the end?

Tags: ios, sorting, alphabetical

Hopefully this isn't a repetitive question, but I haven't been able to find the solution anywhere. I'm sorting keys in a NSDictionary using

```
sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)
```

Everything is working great, except this returns my "#" key first. I'd prefer to return it after the "A-Z" keys. It's the only non-alphabet key.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you only have one # key or more than one

Answer (score 1):

So use sortedArrayUsingComparator instead, and use a custom comparator block that first checks for your "#" key, and specifies it should be after other strings, and returns the result of localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare for everything else. See if you can work that out, and if not post back with the code you tried and I'll help you debug it. (Are you using Objective-C or Swift?)

Comment: I'm using Obj-C. I'll give it a shot and report back!

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick:

`sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *a, NSString *b) {
                if ([a isEqualToString:@"#"]) {
                    return NSOrderedDescending;
                } else if ([b isEqualToString:@"#"]) {
                    return NSOrderedAscending;
                } else {
                    return [a compare:b];
                }
            }`

Comment: Looks good, except you should probably use `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` in your else clause since that's what you used in your question.